# Routing on symfony 1.4 doesen't works

Tags: php

I have a working website on symfony 1.4 framework. My task is to move it on subdomain. I copied all files and set all settings for database. But on subdomain I have a problem - I can take access to only main page and onli using url like mysite.com/web/index.php. And all links on site doesent work too. 
I cleared cache and tried to chancge routing.yml. But I didn't have results. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Wow! 1.4?! You shouldn't have to go to /web/index.php. /web/ should be your Web root. Have you tried just mysite.com/index.php. Please provide more information on errors...

Comment: mysite.com/index.php doesen't works. All links become like /web/delivery and gives me 404 error.

Comment: You need to provide more information on the errors. What's in the logs? Have you tested the sub domain is working properly first using a simple php file in the root to echo out a message?

Comment: In logs nothing. Subdomain is working. Just now I copied all files from floder web to root and I now I can access to main page. But all links doesen't works. For example mysite.com/contacts gives me 404.

Answer (score 0):

I found that I can get access to all urls using site.com/web/index.php/needed_url. So I just set in .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^$ index.html [QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.html [QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```